# What is the "Kos Shel Ikrin," a potion that renders one infertile?

Tags: talmud-gemara, medicine, pregnancy-birth, science, rationalism

The Talmud discusses the "Kos Shel Ikrin" (Cup of the Barren, or Cup of Roots), a potion that rendered a woman or man infertile. The recipe for this potion is on record in tractate Shabbos and there was no question that this potion did exactly what it was purported to do (see Yevamos 65b, Shabbos 110b, and many other sources). In fact, its success was certain (see Tosafos in Shabbos 110b). Apparently the brewing of a Kos Shel Ikrin was still a known process in the days of the Rambam (he describes the ingredients in his Perush LeMishnayos).

Does such a potion exist today?

Comment: Just imagining here ... perhaps it's something that has a 100% chance of rendering someone sterile but a 40% chance of also killing them? That might be why it's not in the medical literature today.

Comment: It also sounds like it was a one-time treatment; certainly there are herbs known as contraceptives (though needed on an ongoing basis) today, I heard about one of those in the Amazon rainforest, I think.

Comment: @Shalom, if there was significant risk to life, it would have been prohibited on those grounds. The Talmud in Shabbos only discusses the "Sirus" problem, and some hold that women may take it. But it is possible that a person would become weaker or otherwise impaired.

Comment: The Kos Shel Ikrin was not guaranteed as you can see in Breishis. The Possuk says that Lemech married two wives, Ada and Tzila. Rashi tells us that in that generation they would marry two wives, one for the purpose of having children and the second for her beauty. They would give the second wife a "kos shel ikrin" to make her sterile. Ada was the wife for having children and Tzila was for her beauty. Two verses later we see Tzila having children. This shows it was not guaranteed.

Comment: @Gershon Medical technology could well have evolved between the pre-Noahide and medieval eras.

Comment: See the Tosfos I cited, where they hold there was a sufficient degree of certainty, although there may have been rare exceptions. Besides, many things w.r.t. biology were different pre-Mabul.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's "kos shel *akarin*"

Comment: @jake Assuming they are the same roots in the baby-protecting amulet according to Rash"i ("תלי קמיע - של עיקרין") in [Kidushin 73b](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%92_%D7%91) I think it should be "_ikrin_".

Comment: @WAF, I wonder, though. The word is עָקָר,‎ עֲקָרָה, like חָכָם,‎ חֲכָמָה,‎ חֲכָמִים, so it looks like it should be עֲקָרִים(/ן)‏ — but that's Biblical Hebrew (_lashon hakodesh_). _L'shon Chazal_ may well differ. (Of course, this assumes the word means "barren person". If it means "extracts" or something, then never mind.)

Comment: @msh210 I kind of assumed it meant 'roots', but I was basing that on instinct alone.

Comment: @WAF, well, at least that (or 'extracts") fits the spelling found in the _Rashi_ you quote.

Comment: @Barry, Are you asking if we know what the modern-day ingredients of the potion are, or if people still make it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterilization_%28surgical_procedure%29#.22Sterilization_pill.22 There is no drug that can cause permanent sterility. However, there are many herbs and plants that act as abortificants. So perhaps that's what it was (although I could not say which specific plant).

For example these:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daucus_carota
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silphium
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asafoetida

act as both abortificants and contraceptives.